# Recursive URL Authentication with Django-Allauth

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-allauth

I am building a dashboard for my app and using django-allauth for authentication. How can I require that all my views require login that are recursive to my dashboard url without explicitly setting it on each one? The view below is the home page of my dashboard. Thank you.

```
@verified_email_required
def back_office_index(request):
    return render(request, 'backoffice/index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a middleware for that, something like this:

```
from allauth.account.decorators import verified_email_required

class VerifiedEmailRequiredMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/dashboard'):
            return verified_email_required(lambda r: None)(request)
```

Comment: I added this to my view but nothing happened and I searched for the middleware class to add to my settings file, but didn't see one.  Am I missing something?  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "added this to my view". You don't add middleware to your view. Put the above code in `yourproject/some_app/middleware.py` and make sure your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` contains an entry `yourproject.some_app.middleware.VerifiedEmailRequiredMiddleware`.

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning Django.  I've tried your suggestion but in console I get a very long string `.../dashboard/accounts/login/%25252525252525252525252525253Fnext%25252525252525252525252525253D/dashboard/accounts/login/%2525252525252525252525252525253Fnext%252525252525252525252525252525253D/dashboard/accounts/login/%25252525252525252525252525252525253Fnext%25252525252525252525252525252525253D/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
...` - I've tried different variations of the path set in the code above but nothing works.

Comment: @StudioRooster, you have a redirect loop. This middleware needs to exclude the login and verification urls (or something like that). Otherwise, the verification requirements sends the user to the login or verification page, which runs the verification requirement, which turns into an infinite redirect loop. The way it is implemented above, it does exclude it. You probably modified it and it does not exclude it anymore.